# How to fix this network issue for my desktop?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, desktop-computer

Recently I've been having some network trouble with the desktop in my living room. Right now I have Comcast internet service, which is the 50 Mbps plan. Now on my desktop computer, I've only been getting roughly 3-4 Mbps speed. The technicians from Comcast came and looked at it and said everything is fine from their side, which is indeed true.

This is because if I use my laptop and wirelessly connect to the network, the speed is fine, of course with the speed dropping when I move away from the router, but that is expected. If I hardwire it, the speed is fine, no matter where it is wired from in my home. So I decided to do some testing today to determine what might be the cause of this issue. I took my laptop to the living room and hardwired it with a 30 foot long Ethernet cable and my speed was around 60-70 Mbps. I did the same with my desktop, and the speed was, again only 3-4 Mbps (I made sure the wireless was off).

I do have an Asus PCE-N15 wireless card in the desktop and I've updated all of its drivers as well. I also took the wireless card out and just used the basic LAN connection I already have with the motherboard and updated those drivers (which were already up to date). The last thing I did was change up the DNS settings but none of that worked. My speed on the desktop was still 3-4 Mbps.

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue? I can't seem to figure out what the issue is, considering my laptop worked fine when doing the testing like I did with the desktop. Will I have to change up some more settings on the desktop to fix this? I would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any "internet protection suites" or alike installed? 3rd party firewalls? Assuming Windows, does it behave the same in Safe Mode with Networking?  If you boot off a Linux LiveCD (or alike) does it behave the same way?

Comment: I have Microsoft Security Essentials downloaded on it. But I also have the same suite on my laptop as well. However, I did try to boot this in safe mode just now and the speed is MUCH higher than running normally. Wireless is around 10-12 Mbps, which is understandable, considering my laptop has a much better network adapter than the desktop. But connecting it wired was perfect speed, getting around 55-60 Mbps. Would a certain program possibly be causing the speed to be significantly reduced when booting normally?

Comment: @techie007 I used some malware removing software and it fixed up a few things, however it still runs slow. Any idea how I might be able to determine which programs are disabled during safe mode so I can disable them one by one in normal mode to find which one it is that is causing the slow network speeds?